# Annoying Tomcat issue with WAR files

Tags: java, tomcat, firefox, locking, war

I am having an annoying issue with Apache Tomcat's handling of WAR files.

After deploying a WAR file using Tomcat Web Application Manager, the file becomes locked. I can not delete it, rename it or do anything with it. Stopping the application, undeploying it and even stopping Tomcat does not help - I need to restart Windows.

P.S. I'm running Tomcat 8.5.9 on Windows 7.

P.P.S. My quick internet search reveals a few mentions like "Yeah, right, that happens" - but nothing like a major showstopper that I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

I figured what was going on. Tomcat is off the hook.
What was holding a lock was a web browser (Firefox) where Tomcat Web Application Manager was loaded. As soon as I close the Tomcat tab in my browser, file lock is released.

Interestingly enough, this behavior seem to be specific to Firefox. Chrome was good, while IE 11 could not even properly deploy the war.